# Using ProcessBuilder with argument list as single String

Tags: java, processbuilder

I try to switch from `Runtime.exec(command)` to `ProcessBuilder` for executing ImageMagick's `convert` from a Java programm. The options for convert are passed-in from the user as a String, so I cannot easily separate the arguments to pass them indvidually to `ProcessBuilder`'s constructor. The actual command that works on the (Unix) commandline is

```
convert -colorspace gray -enhance -density 300 in.pdf out.pdf
```

How can I get this could to work:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String convertOptions = "-colorspace gray -enhance -density 300"; // arguments passed in at runtime
        ProcessBuilder bp = new ProcessBuilder(new String []{"convert",convertOptions,"in.pdf","out.pdf"});
        Process process = bp.start();
        process.waitFor();
    }
}
```

Currently, the code justs run

Comment: Split convertOptions with " " as delims and use them to construct convertOptions? If you pass the whole string , it will consider whole string as a parameter. Its not what you want I presume.

Comment: you are right of cause, but I do not need to split on " ", but on "-"

Answer (score 3):

Old question but since I'm facing a similar situation...

If you don't want to split the command string into an array you could execute the whole string using `bash -c`:

```
String convert= "convert -colorspace gray -enhance -density 300";
String[] cmd= new String[] {"bash", "-c", convert};
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
...
```

This of course assumes `bash` is available.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to get your params like in the code below:

```
String regex = "((\\s*|-)\\w+)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
String convertOptions = "-colorspace gray -enhance -density 300"; // //arguments passed in at runtime
Matcher matcher  = p.matcher(convertOptions);
List<String> pargs = new ArrayList<String>();
pargs.add("convert");
while(matcher.find())
{
   String match = matcher.group();
   if( match != null )
   {
      pargs.add(match.trim());
   }
}
pargs.add("in.pdf");
pargs.add("out.pdf");

try
{
    ProcessBuilder bp = new ProcessBuilder( pargs.toArray(new String[]{}) );
    Process process = bp.start();
    process.waitFor();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```